# Adjust the height of scrollview according to the height of his child tableview in SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a viewController, with a tableview inside a scrollview.

I need to update programmatically the height of the tableview, and then, the height of the scrollview (scrollview's height depends on tableview's height).

```
-my View Controller
  -View
    -ScrollView
      -Container View
        -TableView
```

So I wrote this code in the viewDidAppear of my viewController :

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var frame:CGRect = self.tableView.frame
    frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
    self.tableView.frame = frame

    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.frame.height)

 }
```

If I check in the console, viewDidAppear is called BEFORE all the cellForRowAtIndexPath. In this case, everything works as I want.

In my viewController, I have a button that opens a modalViewController. In this modalViewController,  I add a new data in my tableview (so, a new cell).

When I close my modalViewController with dismissViewControllerAnimated, viewDidAppear is called but AFTER all the cellForRowAtIndexPath.
My viewController is not displayed correctly, the tableview is cropped, I cannot scroll to the bottom of my tableView. My code doesn't work.

I'm working with Swift and auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this in your view controller:

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

You can also set it in Interface Builder if you prefer